# TRY_PARSE makes function Non-Deterministic

Tags: sql-server

I want to make calculated column persisted, but TRY_PARSE makes my function Non-Deterministic. Can I do something with that? Is there replacement?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[F] 
(
    @input nvarchar(100)
)
RETURNS int
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    return TRY_PARSE(@input as INT)
END


SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[F]'), 'IsDeterministic')
```

Comment: `TRY_PARSE` is always nondeterministic and any use of it in a function renders it nondeterministic. There may be a workaround depending on what you want the function to do (most obviously not using `TRY_PARSE`, of course) but that depends on your context. `CONVERT` is deterministic, for example, but that may not offer the conversions you need. You can also implement your own conversion as a CLR function and mark it deterministic. What's the function even for, though? Functions in T-SQL are usually not half as helpful as you might think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TRY_CONVERT` instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[F] 
(
    @input nvarchar(100)
)
RETURNS int
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    return TRY_CONVERT(INT,@input)
END


SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[F]'), 'IsDeterministic')
```